# Deploying a MERN app on heroku with two separate folders

Tags: heroku, deployment, web-deployment, heroku-cli

I want to deploy a MERN app on heroku. My git folder structure is like this

```
Repo
|
|---Frontend
|    --src
|    --package.json
|
|
|---Backend
|     --src
|     --package.json
|
|--readme.MD
```

I am unable to find heroku deployment methods **similar to this folder structure** and other methods do not seem to work for me. Steps on how to deploy my project would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As per the Heroku documentation, you cant deploy frontend and backend like this on a Single Heroku dyno.

*According to many communities and experts, Heroku's model is to run one app per dyno (and often many dynos for a single app).*

But wait, there is a case in which two servers are deployed to a single dyno and it worked too. You can check it here: https://medium.com/@nadayar/heroku-fu-multiple-servers-on-one-dyno-6fc68d57b373

Hope this solves your problem!

Answer (score 0):

send all server files one level up...

and then in package.json of your server write this under "scripts"

```
 "heroku-postbuild": "npm run instal-client && npm run build",
"instal-client": "cd ../client && npm install",
```

Comment: Is it really "instal-client" or rather "install-client"?

Comment: @Nexonus since typo is in both lines of code it will work

Comment: oh I see. Didn't catch that.